# How to generate the same signature as the JWT.IO website does?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, oauth, jwt

The [JWT.IO](http://jwt.io) website has a debugger for creating and validating JSON Web Token.

When I copy and paste my secret string into the VERIFY SIGNATURE block, I can see that it generates a signature.

[image: JWT.IO]

I scroll down the page a little bit and found [the .NET solution implemented by Microsoft](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet). After downloading, I add my unit test to generate the signature manually.

[image: Unit Test]

However, the signature generated by the JWT.IO website is slightly different from the one generated by my unit test.

```
Secrect string: "THIS IS A SECRET STRING WHICH CAN BE SHARED BETWEEN THE SERVICES"
Unit test signature: "B0d57pcHoDiTDE/98dyrMx9HoFKGLOcM094eYBgJqHo="
JWT.IO    signature:  B0d57pcHoDiTDE_98dyrMx9HoFKGLOcM094eYBgJqHo
```

I notice that the JWT.IO signature string is URL encoding safe, but the unit test signature is not.

How do I generate the same signature as the JWT.IO website does?

### UPDATE

The accepted answer below pointed me to [the class `Base64UrlEncoder`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/Base64UrlEncoder.cs). I have modified my unit test to generate the exact same signature as JWT.IO web site does:

[image: Use Base64UrlEncoder]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Believe2014 It seems that the `jwt.io` website does not have some options for specifying the base64 encoding with which way of URLEncoding to generate the same signature as your unit test.

However, according to the section 4 & 5 of [`RFC 4648`](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-4648.txt), the differences between both signatures are using different characters for byte `62` & `63` and whether omits padding characters `=`.

So for converting the signature generated by `jwt.io` into yours, just using `/` instead of `_`, using `+` instead of `-`, and adding the padding characters `=` at the end of signature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to find the class `Base64UrlEncoder` in Mircosoft's source code that does similar replacement steps as you described.  https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/Base64UrlEncoder.cs